# List arguments for a specific command within each section

Tags: macros, table-of-contents, environments, scoping, environment-variables

How can I limit the scope of a command to a given section?

I have adapted a macro found online which reads in the arguments from a command and lists them

```
\newcommand{\printDefn}{}
  \newcommand\defn[2]{\begin{definition}{\textbf{#1} {#2}}\end{definition}
     \g@addto@macro{\printDefn}{\item \textbf{#1} \space : \space #2}
  }
```

My goal is to have this done per section. The problem is that every time `\printDefn` is called it (understandably) prints all the definitions in the document, not just the new ones.

Is there a way to limit the scope, of the command so that it looks only at the current section? Or is there some `if ... else` construct I could use to print only if `currrentSection == firstNumbering` ?

## EDIT

```
\section{}

\defn{test}{from 1}



\begin{enumerate}
\printDefn
\end{enumerate}

\section{}

\defn{test}{from 2}


\renewcommand{\printDefn}{}

\begin{enumerate}
\printDefn
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The easiest way out is to do `\renewcommand{\printDefn}{}` at every section to clear the list in `\printDefn`

Comment: Thanks @PhelypeOleinik ! `\renewcommand{\printDefn}{}` seems to override the original macro in the class. When calling `printDefn` inside the `enumerate` environment, it complains that there there is a missing item. Did you mean declaring the whole block in each section?

Comment: You need to first _use_ `\printDefn` and only then clear it (outside the `enumerate` environment) using `\renewcommand`. A perhaps mode clever way (untested): `\newcommand{\printDefn}{\gdef\defnlist{}\defnlist}
\newcommand\defn[2]{\begin{definition}{\textbf{#1} {#2}}\end{definition}
  \g@addto@macro{\defnlist}{\item \textbf{#1} \space : \space #2}}`.

Comment: That's what I did (see edit above). Using `\show` to evaluate the command I get `\printDefn=\long macro: ->.` instead of evaluating to the definition as the first one does. Your other suggestion throws an undefined error for `\defnlist`

Comment: As I said, untested ;-) The version in your edit doesn't work because you clear `\printDefn` (with `\renewcommand{\printDefn}{}`) before using it in the second `enumerate` environment. You have to clear it _after_ using. Here's a (hopefully) fixed version of my suggestion: `\newcommand{\printDefn}{\defnlist\gdef\defnlist{}}\newcommand\defnlist{}
\newcommand\defn[2]{\begin{definition}{\textbf{#1} {#2}}\end{definition}
  \g@addto@macro{\defnlist}{\item \textbf{#1} \space : \space #2}}`

Comment: It's alive! Thanks! If you have the time I would really appreciate if you could write up an answer explaining what's going on, and I'll mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks again :)

Comment: The problem with your version was that you made `\printDefn` empty before using it, so you had essentially `\begin{enumerate}\end{enumerate}`, which is invalid. My version stores the definitions in `\defnlist` and `\printDefn` just typesets them and clears the list in `\defnlist` automatically (with `\gdef\defnlist{}`). egreg's version is essentially the same, except that he uses a toks register instead of a macro and he resets the list at every `\section` command. I'm not at the computer right now, so I can' write a proper answer. You can accept his :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the code for resetting the list to `\section`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\xpretocmd{\section}{\global\saveddefinitions{}}{}{}

\newtoks\saveddefinitions

\newcommand\defn[2]{%
  \begin{definition}\textbf{#1} #2\end{definition}%
  \global\saveddefinitions\expandafter{%
    \the\saveddefinitions
    \item \textbf{#1}: #2%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\printDefn}{\begin{enumerate}\the\saveddefinitions\end{enumerate}}

\begin{document}

\section{A}

\defn{test}{from 1}

\printDefn

\section{B}

\defn{test}{from 2}

\printDefn

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your contribution! Phelype's solution is working and is closer to what I had, so I'm just gonna go with it